# fftw3 floating point FFT yields only zeros

Tags: c++, fft, fftw

I want to use FFTW3 with FP32 precision for a R2C FFT. I reconfigured the library with  `./configure --enable-float --enable-type-prefix`, then `make` and `make install`. Then I linked with `-L/path/to/fftw_f/.libs/ -lfftw3f -lm` and changed all used function prefixes to `fftwf_`. Here is the code snipped I'm using:

```
#include "path/to/fftw3/api/fftw3.h"
typedef std::complex<float> complexf;

int N0 = some_int;
size_t N1 = some_int2;
float *input = input_data_array;
complexf *out = (complexf *) fftwf_malloc(sizeof(complexf) * size_of_output);


fftwf_plan plan;
plan = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N0, N1, input, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex *>(&out), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftwf_execute(plan);
fftwf_destroy_plan(plan);
```

Somehow this does just yield zeros in the output, which is not correct when comparing it to working FFTW3 FP64 version of the algorithm.

I already checked that the input is casted correctly to FP32. Is there anything else I'm missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you can do `reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex *>(&out)`? Looks to me like [type aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) violation. However it might not be the root cause of your issue.

Comment: "this does just yield zeros in the output" is not "yields no results" like your title says.  Which is it?

Comment: @possum sorry for the confusion. I get -0.00 and 0.00 in no particular order, so I guess it might yield output, but just zeros.

Comment: @pptaszni Thanks for the hint, but using `reinterpret_cast` worked out for me in the correct version with FP64, so haven't considered it.

Comment: @pptaszni the error remains without the `reinterpret_cast`. I have the feeling that FFTW3 is not doing anything under the hood (but without throwing any errors), because execution time drops drastically by a factor of 10.

Comment: Hmm oki, can you then post complete example to reproduce? With `int main`, sample input (if possible, e.g. can it be just white noise?), and sample numbers you are using (`N0`, `N1`). Highlight the difference between working 64bit solution and not working 32bit approach.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], pseudocode is really hard to debug!

Comment: @pptaszni I will provide a minimal example in a minute. I used [this](http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_6.html) to install fftw3 with `./configure --enable-float --enable-type-prefix` as instructed for float configuration, but `--enable-type-prefix` does not seem to be used for the current version. I received: `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-type-prefix`.

Comment: You're reading the FFTW 2 documentation, the current version is 3.3.10. Here's the installation instructions for the 3.3 version of the library: http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-on-Unix.html